# Default template not at the end

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Can someone tell me the purpose for a default template value as in

```
  template <typename, typename = void, int...> struct foo {};
```

when declaring `foo<int, void, 5>` will compile but `foo<int, 5>` will not?
Isn't the purpose of `typename = void` so that we can omit that entry so that it will be `void` by default?  If such syntax is not allowed, then why have the default value there at all?

Comment: It would be more trouble than it's worth making `foo<int, 5>` be smart enough to skip the default and move on to the `int...`. Sure it's easy enough in this case, but as soon as you try to generalize it, you run into ambiguities and other complications.

Comment: It's difficult to mix default template arguments and variadic templates.

Comment: It's hard to say with literally zero context why a piece of code exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a parameter pack can be empty, in this example `foo<int>` will compile. Without the default argument, you explicitly need `foo<int, void>`.